# Selecting Data from Same Table that Doesn't Match

Tags: sql, t-sql, self-join

I have found several solutions for my type of problem, but I having trouble applying it in my situation.

Essentially I have a Vehicle Table:

```
License     VIN     Region
1           1       1
1           2       2
2           3       1
2           3       2
3           4       1
3           4       2
3           5       3
```

I want to take the license and vin from region 1 and see if the vin matches in all other regions based on the license.  If it doesn't I want all the rows that don't match, but if it does match I don't want the row.  So a complexity does come in when say I have 3 licenses and region 1 matches one row, but not the other, I want both the unmatched and region 1; however, when I have 3 licenses that all match I don't want any rows including region 1.

So my results in this case would be:

```
License     VIN     Region
1           1       1
1           2       2
3           4       1
3           5       3
```

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: It is like a tongue twister :) Can you add the steps you performed in more detail to get that result?

Comment: The query would go through row by row in this order for region 1. 
Start

Grab license and vin.

Look to see if license matches (if no match go back to start)

if match check vin (if match look for next license, if no next license don't add row go back to start)

if no match add both row in results

go back to check for next license match or start if no more license matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* 
FROM Vehicle AS a
INNER JOIN Vehicle AS b
ON a.License = b.License
WHERE a.VIN != b.VIN 
AND a.Region != b.Region 
AND (a.Region = 1 OR b.Region = 1)
```

Comment: Will this always grab from region 1 first?  My concern with this is that other region VIN's can match, but I am essentially using region 1 as the key VIN.

Comment: I reread your question and added another WHERE clause so there there has to be at least one Region 1 record.

Comment: With the added WHERE clause I no longer get region 1 results, only other regions that match the criteria.

Comment: Oh yeah. It's gotta be either a.region=1 or b.region=1. Updated.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was working properly or not as I needed to add more criteria on my end to filter out irrelevant data, but this is a good solution. Thanks